# Flask SqlAlchemy Join returns just an ID value

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Join returns just an ID value rather than the actual data.

Relationship: **1 to Many = Client : PaymentHistory**

**Issue:**
payment_history property is just 1, 2, 3 which is the ID of PaymentHistoy

**Expected Result:**
payment_history must contain actual data instead of ID value

**client_model.py**

```py
class Client(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    pending_amount = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    invoices = db.relationship('Invoice', backref='client', lazy='select')
    payment_history = db.relationship('PaymentHistory',
                                      backref='client',
                                      lazy='select')
```

**payment_history.py**

```py
class PaymentHistory(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    payment_mode = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    amount = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    client_id = db.Column(db.Integer,
                          db.ForeignKey('client.id'),
                          nullable=False)
```

**route_handler.py**

```py
@client_blueprint.route('/get_all', methods=['POST'])
def get_all():
    cli = db.session.query(Client).join(PaymentHistory).all()
    clients = ClientSchema(many=True).dump(cli).data
    return jsonify({'clients': clients})
```

**client_schema.py**

```py
class ClientSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
```

**output**

```js
{
    "clients": [
        {
            "created_at": "2019-06-14T02:12:08.038526+00:00",
            "id": 1,
            "invoices": [],
            "payment_history": [
                1, 2, 3
            ],
            "pending_amount": 0,
            "updated_at": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does the result change using [`joinedload()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.joinedload) instead of `join()`?

Comment: db.session.query(Client).options(joinedload(Client.payment_history)).all()
returns the same result.

Comment: Prolly related to how `ClientSchema` is defined.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I have just added find the ClientSchema before the output section. I am using Flask Marshmallow serializer here. 
https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: [This thread solved my problem with Nested schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41858807/flask-marshmallow-sqlalchemy-serializing-many-to-many-relationships)